# How to delte the running files run with nohup command?

Tags: nohup

Can you suggest me how to kill the running files which start with nohup ./filename.sh?
In my file large number of the files but I want to stop to run these file.

Comment: Please add ./filename.sh details, what it contains?

Comment: I contains the large number of the input mdst file. Due to large number the background jobs are running continuously.